# В чем отличие между React.createClass и class extends React.component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Недавно начал учить React по видео-урокам. Пробовал писать всякие "штуки" на нем и как-то наткнулся на переведенную на русский официальную документацию вот с таким вот примером:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: ''};
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        alert('Text field value is: ' + this.state.value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div>
                    <input type="text"
                     placeholder="Hello!"
                     value={this.state.value}
                     onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                        Submit
                    </button>
                 </div>
             );
    }
}

 ReactDOM.render(
     <Form />,
     document.getElementById('root')
 );
```

В видео-уроках по которым учился я было немного не так, а именно:

1. В чем отличие от создание компонента путем наследования class Form extends React.Component от обычного React.createClass()?
2. Зачем в конструкторе класса привязывается this с помощью bind, если оно и без этого работает?
3. В чем вообще преимущество кода из документации перед моим кодом? (ниже)

```
var Form = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            value: ""
        }
    },
    handleChange(e){
        this.setState({value: e.target.value});
    },
    handleSubmit(e){
        alert("Text field value is: " + this.state.value);
    },
    render: function(){
            return (
                <div>
                    <input type="text"
                     placeholder="Hello!"
                     value={this.state.value}
                     onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                        Submit
                    </button>
                 </div>
             );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
        <Form />,
        document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Заранее спасибо:3

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Это два способа сделать одно и то же.
В самом фейсбуке считают es6 классы более семантически верными и лелеют себя мыслью когда-нибудь в далеком-далеком счастливом будущем поддержку React.createClass прекратить ([**источник**](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/10/react-v0.13.html), первый абзац). Но будет это не в ближайший год и не в два, пока `createClass` даже не deprecated.

Ответ на ваш третий вопрос: **пока это два равнозначных способа.**
Лучше привыкать писать es6-классы, но как там будет в будущем на самом деле предсказать сложно.

**Главные отличия:**

1. Классы - это es6 фича. Соответственно вся транспиляторская магия для полноценной работы с es6 у вас должна присутствовать.
2. В `React.createClass` внутри работает тайная магия которая автоматически биндит все методы переданные в `createClass` к this. В компонентах es6-классов от такой штуки решили отказаться, потому что она часто смущала разработчиков, и биндить надо ручками. Оттуда кстати вытекает ответ на ваш второй вопрос: **без этого - не работает.**
3. В компонентах-es6-классах нет миксинов. Совет мудрецов разрабатывающих реакт решил что миксины нехорошо, хорошо - композиция. И решил не давать возможность писать нехорошо в новых версиях.
4. Вместо `getInitialState` используется `constructor` так как решили что это идиоматичнее для es6 классов, также `propTypes` - свойство самого класса, вместо метода `getDefaultProps` есть свойство класса `defaultProps`

Возможно есть еще какие-то отличия о которых я не вспомню, лично у меня в рабочем проекте есть и createClass в старом коде и es6 классы в новом. getInitialState аутобиндинг и propTypes - это явные заметные отличия, es6 итак уже обычно есть, миксины используют довольно редко.

Answer (score 4):

Новые разработчики `React` часто путаются, когда сталкиваются с двумя разными стилями для объявления компонентов `React`.
В настоящее время экосистема `React` разделена между декларацией компонента `React.createClass`:

```
const MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return(<p>I am a component!</p>);
  }
});
```

И декларацией компонента класса `ES6`:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(<p>I am a component, too!</p>);
  }
}
```

В чем разница между компонентами класса `React.createClass` и `ES6`? И почему они оба существуют?

Как язык на прототипах, `JavaScript` не имел классов на протяжении большей части своего существования. `ES6`, последняя версия `JavaScript`, завершенная **в июне 2015 года**, ввела классы как `синтаксический сахар`.

> Синтаксис класса не представляет для JavaScript новую объектно-ориентированную модель наследования. Классы JavaScript обеспечивают гораздо более простой и понятный синтаксис для создания объектов и работы с наследованием.

Поскольку `JavaScript` не имел классов, `React` включал собственную систему классов. `React.createClass` позволяет создавать компоненты классов. Под капотом ваш компонентный класс использует систему классов на заказ, реализованную в `React`.

С помощью `ES6` `React` позволяет реализовать классы компонентов, которые используют классы `JavaScript ES6`. Конечный результат одинаков - у вас есть класс компонентов. Но стиль отличается. И один использует **пользовательскую** систему классов `JavaScript (createClass)`, в то время как другой использует **родную** систему классов `JavaScript`.

С тех пор сообщество переключается на компоненты класса `ES6`. Это по уважительной причине. Оно использовало `createClass`, потому что у `JavaScript` не было встроенной системы классов. Но `ES6` получила быстрое принятие. И с `ES6`, вместо того, чтобы изобретать колесо, `React` может использовать простой класс `ES6 JavaScript`.

К разработчику различия между компонентами, созданными с `ES6-классами` и `React createClass`, к счастью минимальны. Если вы научились писать компоненты `React` с помощью `createClass`, и если вы когда-либо захотите использовать классы `ES6`, вы легко найдете переход.