# Не могу вызвать Action

Tags: reactjs, redux

Добрый день.

Пишу приложение `React` + `Redux`. Мой компонент выглядит так:

```
import React from 'react';

class HeaderContainer extends React.Component {

onGetBtnClick(e) {
    this.props.loadPresentations()
}

render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Header</h1>
            <button className='btn' onClick={this.onGetBtnClick}>loadPresentations</button>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default HeaderContainer;
```

При этом в лог браузера выводится:

```
Object {user: Object, loadPresentations: function}
```

Т.е. функция `loadPresentations` там есть. А вызваль я ее не могу. Пишет

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null.

А вот `user` могу.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вызвать `Action`?

Comment: В случае использования es6 классов в реакте он не автобиндинт методы к инстансу компонента в отличие от React.createClass

Comment: 1. экшены надо импортировать 2. их надо диспатчить, а не как обычную функцию вызывать

Comment: То есть вам надо либо написать в конструкторе класса this.onGetBtnClick = this.onGetBtnClick.bind(this) (предпочтительно) либо в обработчике onClick={this.onGetBtnClick.bind(this}

Comment: Также есть шанс что вам может слегка помочь этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637479/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-react-createclass-%D0%B8-class-extends-react-component/637502#637502

Comment: Также как уже упомянул @greybutton редаксом в этом конкретном куске кода не пахнет) В заголовке вопроса одно, в в вопросе - другое

Comment: Спасибо, надо было забиндить: {this.onGetBtnClick.bind(this}

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУкрываться оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ